# Relative directory paths in Visual Studio using FSharp

Tags: visual-studio, f#

I have a file located in a solution directory like this:

[image]

I want to read the contents of one of the .txt files into a string in the FSI:

```
open System.IO

[<Literal>]
let path = "../Data/Build_Keynote2014.txt"

let buildKeynote =  File.ReadAllText(path)
```

The problem is that it is throwing an exception:

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\jamie\AppData\Local\Data\Build_Keynote2014.txt'.
```

Is there a way to reference the file without using the full path?

Thanks

Comment: Is the path it is using correct? If not, what is? Have you assumed the correct working directory?

Comment: of course but you have to *dig* for it - most likely your code will run in `/bin/Debug` so you have to do the `..` twice (I think): `let path = "../../Data/..."`  - but it should be easy to check for you - it tells you the *wrong* path - it should be obvious how to rectify it (**btw**: you are obvious on windows, so maybe you should use "\" instead of "/"  in your paths )

Comment: @Carsten, forward slash works fine on Windows.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin to my experience sadly not everywhere (cmd comes to mind) - it was meant as a precaution

Answer (score 8):

After some research, I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233234.aspx) post

```
let baseDirectory = __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__
let baseDirectory' = Directory.GetParent(baseDirectory)
let filePath = "Data\Build_Keynote2014.txt"
let fullPath = Path.Combine(baseDirectory'.FullName, filePath)
let buildKeynote =  File.ReadAllText(fullPath)
```

works like a charm.  Thanks everyone who submitted.

Comment: I also find it's convenient to do a `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory <- System.IO.Path.Combine(__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__, @"bin\Debug")` to ensure my repl environment is like my debug environment.

Comment: "Data\\Build_Keynote2014.txt" - additional backslash to escape it.